# Where did my points go?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have a question about my Christianity Stack Exchange post: [God was born of Mary - really?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/94635/god-was-born-of-mary-really)

Where did my points go? I received no explanation after several days (let alone hours) of being reduced to 1. Is this normal practice here for mods to be heavy-handed?

Comment: Points may have been taken away concerning other of your posts.

Comment: Yes, I don't see anything odd about the post you linked to, but one of your other posts was flagged as rude/offensive.

Comment: whatever was deemed so should have had the opportunity for remedial action. None was provided and 60 odd points went missing without comment or explanation. The post is not the issue here (whatever offense was taken is quite possibly due to someone being offended - which is a popular response these days to practically everything) but the total lack of explanation.

Comment: My guess is that it was taken away from the way the system is set up, so no notification would have been given.

Comment: Having a post deleted by the system for receiving six rude/abusive flags triggers a 100 rep penalty. Check your deleted posts for one that has been marked as spam/rude/abusive.

Comment: @Thomas very useful, thanks

Answer (score 6):

**Where did my points go?**

Do not know where your points went, but there are a few reasons points can be taken away!

> You lose reputation when:
>
> - your question is voted down: −2
> - your answer is voted down: −2
> - you vote down an answer: −1
> - you place a bounty on a question: − full bounty amount
> - one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags: −100
>
> All users start with one reputation point, and reputation can never drop below 1. Accepting your own answer does not increase your reputation. Deleted posts do not affect reputation, for voters, authors or anyone else involved, in most cases. If a user reverses a vote, the corresponding reputation loss or gain will be reversed as well. Vote reversal as a result of voting fraud will also return lost or gained reputation.
>
> [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

Moderators may or may not be involved in this. Like anyone else a moderator may flag a post if it is inappropriate in one way or another. They are certainly not heavy-handed in the process as the system independently is designed to deal with spam, rude or inappropriate comments, questions and answers that get flagged.

Also answers must answer a particular question being asked and not become a platform to express one’s personal theological viewpoint if they contract the premise of the question at hand. Otherwise it is could considered inappropriate, rude or even spam depending on the situation.

Another example would be calling moderators **”insolent”** and heavy-handed could get this post flagged